# create File from FileOutputStream

Tags: java, file-io, fileoutputstream

I'm using `org.apache.commons.net.ftp` to download files in a remote machine.
There is a method, that reads the files to a `FileOutputStream` object.

```
ftpClient.retrieveFile("/" + ftpFile.getName(), fos);
```

Problem, here is, i've another method that accepts a `File` object.  So, i need to create a `File` object file the `FileOutputStream`.  I think, i need to create an `InputStream` to be able to create a file object from the `FileOutputStream`.  is this correct?  I might be missing something and there should be an easy way to create a `File` from a `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: shouldn't retrieveFile create the InputStream? Shouldn't the File be the one you used to create the FileOutputStream?

Comment: please, what means: "i need to create a File object file the FileOutputStream" ?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - The retrieveFile reads a file through FTP and writes the contents of the file to OutPutStream

Comment: @Gangnus - sorry for the ambiguity.  Since the other method only accept a File, i need to get a File object from FileOutputStream

Comment: You need to know what file was used to create the FileOutputStream, I believe you should be trying to work out what it was after the fact.

Answer (score 6):

FileOutputStream has a constructor that takes a File object.

The following should do what you need it to do:

```
File f = new File("path/to/my/file");
if(f.createNewFile()) { // may not be necessary
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f); // create a file output stream around f
    ftpClient.retrieveFile("/" + ftpFile.getName(), fos);

    otherMethod(f); // pass the file to your other method
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont think i can create a File upfront and pass it to the FileOutputStream, because the actual files names that i'm downloading through FTP will be a primary key of a table and have some business logic around it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in addition to the answer of mcfinnigan, you must know that when you use the code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f); // create a file output stream around f
ftpClient.retrieveFile("/" + ftpFile.getName(), fos);
```

Then an empty file will be created on your filesystem on the first line. Then if the 2nd line throws an exception, because no remote file exist for path `"/" + ftpFile.getName()`, the empty file will still be on your filesystem.

So I've done a little LazyInitOutputStream with Guava to handle that:

```
public class LazyInitOutputStream extends OutputStream {

  private final Supplier<OutputStream> lazyInitOutputStreamSupplier;

  public LazyInitOutputStream(Supplier<OutputStream> outputStreamSupplier) {
    this.lazyInitOutputStreamSupplier = Suppliers.memoize(outputStreamSupplier);
  }

  @Override
  public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    lazyInitOutputStreamSupplier.get().write(b);
  }

  @Override
  public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {
    lazyInitOutputStreamSupplier.get().write(b);
  }

  @Override
  public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    lazyInitOutputStreamSupplier.get().write(b,off,len);
  }


  public static LazyInitOutputStream lazyFileOutputStream(final File file) {
    return lazyFileOutputStream(file,false);
  }

  public static LazyInitOutputStream lazyFileOutputStream(final File file,final boolean append) {
    return new LazyInitOutputStream(new Supplier<OutputStream>() {
      @Override
      public OutputStream get() {
        try {
          return new FileOutputStream(file,append);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          throw Throwables.propagate(e);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I've encoutered this problem while using Spring integration remote.file packages, with the FTP/SFTP file download features. I use it like that to solve this empty file problem:

```
try ( OutputStream downloadedFileStream = LazyInitOutputStream.lazyFileOutputStream(destinationfilePath.toFile()) ) {
  remoteFileSession.read(source, downloadedFileStream);
}
```